# jqGrid modal form with

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to find an example of jqgrid with the following features.

1. an edit icon on each row
2. a delete icon on each row (ideally in a seperate column to the edit icon).
3. local data
4. a modal edit form rather than inline editing

[This](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm) example is the closest that I have seen, but it doesn't have features 1 & 2.
Can someone show me an example with all of these features?

Answer (score 0):

okay so I'm assumimg you have colNames like this for example

['Name', 'Company','Edit', 'Delete']

Now in Edit column for each row you want a custom edit button, Same with delete also, right?

I'm going to write code for custom button, if you don't want custom button then you can go for [action formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter). For this also i'll write code.

**Custom Edit and Delete Button in separate column.**

```
function callMeOnLoadComplete(){
 var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,'Edit'); // 'Edit' - name of the actions column
         grid.children("tbody")
                .children("tr.jqgrow")
                .children("td:nth-child("+(iCol+1)+")")
                .each(function() {
                 $("<div>",
                        {
                            title: "Save",
                            mouseover: function() {
                                $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                            },
                            mouseout: function() {
                                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                            },
                            click: 
                            do sth
                            }
                      ).css({"margin-left": "5px", float:"left"})
                       .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-save")
                       .attr('id',"saveEdits")
                       .append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>')
                       .appendTo($(this).children("div"));

}
```

**call the above function in loadComplete or gridComplete parameters of jqgrid. this for Edit column, similarly you can do for Delete column also.**

```
 var getColumnIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel'), i=0,l=cm.length;
                for (; i<l; i+=1) {
                    if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            };
```

I'm assuming you have jquery custom ui.css because these icons will be picked from the images come along with it.

```
Edit and Delete Button with action formatter
```

with your colModal, for Edit Column do something like this.

```
{ name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', formatter: 'actions',formatoptions: {keys: true,delbutton:false}}
```

The reason i have given delbutton:false because you want delete button in delete Column. If you want it in same column, remove this property else you can use same action formatter in Delete column also and make editbutton:false there.